# What's the difference between du and df?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, disk, ram

I would like to know exactly what `du` and `df` mean.

The following is an example of the output of the `df` command.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ubi0:rootfs     435M  424M   12M  98% /
devtmpfs         88M  4.0K   88M   1% /dev
tmpfs           248M     0  248M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           248M  8.4M  240M   4% /run
tmpfs           248M     0  248M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           248M     0  248M   0% /tmp
tmpfs           248M   72K  248M   1% /var/volatile
```

And here's the output of `du` (run in the `/` directory)

```
 $ du -sh home
    255M    home
 $ du -sh usr
    264M    usr
```

I thought that `ubi0:rootfs` included `/home` and `/usr`, but the sum of them, 519M,  is larger than the `ubi0:rootfs` size, 435M.

The result of the `free` command is as follows.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           495M         55M         50M        8.4M        389M        420M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

At first I thought the difference is due to ramdisk, but the `free` command shows RAM is not used so much.

What is the exact difference between `du` and `df` (or is the `/usr` dir special)?

Comment: What filesystem?

Comment: The fs is ubifs installed on NAND.

Comment: In that case, you should check ubifs docs to see if classic tools like `df` and `du` can even produce meaningful values for it. This is not the case for some modern filesystems, like btrfs, for example. Otherwise you'd be trying to make sense out of garbage output.

Comment: Directory "/home" can contain hardlinks to files in "/usr"?

Comment: What do you get with `du -shc home usr` (that is one du invocation for both)? What `du` implementation is it?